# Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Call to undefined function App\needsRehash()

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, hash, crypt

I am working on an old laravel project,
when I launch the project everything goes well but when I try to add a user (name, first name, password ..) the error appears.
i am using wamp. i used xampp too and still the same probleme, I can't find any solution please help me.
this is composer.json

```
    {
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.3",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "^1.0",
    "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/passport": "4.0.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5",
    "nesbot/carbon": "2.22.0 as 1.34.0",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^6.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
    "laravel/dusk": "^2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": [
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
  }
}
```

And this is the line of erreur on the project

```
     public function setPasswordAttribute($input)
    {                                                       
        if ($input)
            //Probleme de hashage
           $this->attributes['password'] = needsRehash($input) ? Hash::make($input) : $input;
        
    }
```

Comment: The Error message is clear. Function `needsRehash` called in  `$this->attributes['password'] = needsRehash($input) ? Hash::make($input) : $input;` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `needsRehash` to `Hash::needsRehash`.

To be honest, I'm surprised the Laravel application ever worked, since to my knowledge there has never been `needsRehash` in the framework that wasn't the static method.

For further information consult the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing)

Comment: it  stiil doesn't work form me.Thank you. idk why !! i tried this code too:  ``$this->attributes['password'] = app('hash')->needsRehash($input) ? Hash::make($input) : $input;``                       , and this one too ``$this->attributes['password'] = Hash::needsRehash($input) ? Hash::make($input) : $input;`` THE ERROR STIIL THE SAME